# Altium Layer Stackup - Not Loading Sierra Circuits Layer Stackup Export

Tags: altium, pcb-layers, stack-up

First post. I am trying to load an exported XML file from Sierra Circuits:

[image]

When I go to my Layer Stackup page in my project, then I go to File>Load Stackup From File...

[image]

And it does not show any of the files I've downloaded, even if I select All Stackup Documents.

[image]

I selected all three options to see what I could see, and none of my options changed. Has anyone else had this problem? Did anyone else experience this or fix it?

EDIT: I am attaching the XML File below... if anyone knows a better way please let me know. Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IPC-2581 revision="B" xmlns="http://webstds.ipc.org/2581">
    <Content roleRef="Owner">
        <StepRef name="MyFile_IPC_File"/>
        <LayerRef name="SOLDERMASK_TOP"/>
        <LayerRef name="TOP"/>
        <LayerRef name="DIELECTRIC_INDEX_3"/>
        <LayerRef name="LYR-2_PLANE-1"/>
        <LayerRef name="DIELECTRIC_INDEX_5"/>
        <LayerRef name="LYR-3_PLANE-2"/>
        <LayerRef name="DIELECTRIC_INDEX_7"/>
        <LayerRef name="BOTTOM"/>
        <LayerRef name="SOLDERMASK_BOTTOM"/>
        <DictionaryColor>
            <EntryColor id="COLOR_SOLDERMASK_TOP">
                <Color r="255" g="0" b="0"/>
            </EntryColor>
            <EntryColor id="COLOR_Top">
                <Color r="255" g="0" b="0"/>
            </EntryColor>
            <EntryColor id="COLOR_LYR-2_PLANE-1">
                <Color r="255" g="0" b="0"/>
            </EntryColor>
            <EntryColor id="COLOR_LYR-3_PLANE-2">
                <Color r="255" g="0" b="0"/>
            </EntryColor>
            <EntryColor id="COLOR_Bottom">
                <Color r="0" g="0" b="255"/>
            </EntryColor>
            <EntryColor id="COLOR_SOLDERMASK_BOTTOM">
                <Color r="255" g="0" b="0"/>
            </EntryColor>
        </DictionaryColor>
        <DictionaryLineDesc units="INCH">
            <EntryLineDesc id="ROUND_0">
                <LineDesc lineEnd="ROUND" lineWidth="0.00000"/>
            </EntryLineDesc>
        </DictionaryLineDesc>
        <DictionaryFillDesc units="INCH">
            <EntryFillDesc id="SOLID_FILL">
                <FillDesc fillProperty="FILL"/>
            </EntryFillDesc>
            <EntryFillDesc id="HOLLOW">
                <FillDesc fillProperty="HOLLOW"/>
            </EntryFillDesc>
        </DictionaryFillDesc>
        <DictionaryStandard units="INCH"/>
        <DictionaryUser units="INCH"/>
    </Content>
    <LogisticHeader>
        <Role id="OWNER" roleFunction="SENDER"/>
        <Enterprise id="Sierra Circuit" code="Owner"/>
        <Person name="Designer" enterpriseRef="Sierra Circuit" roleRef="OWNER"/>
    </LogisticHeader>
    <HistoryRecord number="1" origination="2023/09/11 21:16:17" software="Sierra Circuit Stackup Designer 1.1" lastChange="2023/09/11 21:16:17">
        <FileRevision fileRevisionId="1" comment="No Comment">
            <SoftwarePackage name="Stackup Designer" revision="1" vendor="Sierra Circuit">
                <Certification certificationStatus="CERTIFIED"/>
            </SoftwarePackage>
        </FileRevision>
    </HistoryRecord>
    <Ecad name="Design">
        <CadHeader units="INCH">
            <Spec name="SPEC_LAYER_SOLDERMASK_TOP">
                <General type="MATERIAL">
                    <Property text="Soldermask"/>
                </General>
                <Dielectric type="DIELECTRIC_CONSTANT">
                    <Property value="4.2"/>
                </Dielectric>
                <Dielectric type="LOSS_TANGENT">
                    <Property value="0.024"/>
                </Dielectric>
            </Spec>
            <Spec name="SPEC_LAYER_TOP">
                <General type="MATERIAL">
                    <Property text="COPPER"/>
                </General>
                <General type="OTHER" comment="LAYER_TYPE">
                    <Property text="CONDUCTOR"/>
                </General>
                <General type="OTHER" comment="LAYER_EMBEDDED_STATUS">
                    <Property text="NOT_EMBEDDED"/>
                </General>
                <Conductor type="CONDUCTIVITY">
                    <Property unit="MHO/CM" value="595900.000000"/>
                </Conductor>
            </Spec>
            <Spec name="SPEC_LAYER_DIELECTRIC_INDEX_3">
                <General type="MATERIAL">
                    <Property text="FR370HR 1x1080-71%"/>
                </General>
                <General type="OTHER" comment="LAYER_TYPE">
                    <Property text="DIELECTRIC"/>
                </General>
                <Dielectric type="DIELECTRIC_CONSTANT">
                    <Property value="3.63"/>
                </Dielectric>
            </Spec>
            <Spec name="SPEC_LAYER_LYR-2_PLANE-1">
                <General type="MATERIAL">
                    <Property text="COPPER"/>
                </General>
                <General type="OTHER" comment="LAYER_TYPE">
                    <Property text="PLANE"/>
                </General>
                <General type="OTHER" comment="LAYER_IS_SHIELD">
                    <Property text="true"/>
                </General>
                <General type="OTHER" comment="LAYER_EMBEDDED_STATUS">
                    <Property text="NOT_EMBEDDED"/>
                </General>
                <Conductor type="CONDUCTIVITY">
                    <Property unit="MHO/CM" value="595900.000000"/>
                </Conductor>
            </Spec>
            <Spec name="SPEC_LAYER_DIELECTRIC_INDEX_5">
                <General type="MATERIAL">
                    <Property text="FR370HR 0.039 Core"/>
                </General>
                <General type="OTHER" comment="LAYER_TYPE">
                    <Property text="DIELECTRIC"/>
                </General>
                <Dielectric type="DIELECTRIC_CONSTANT">
                    <Property value="4.24"/>
                </Dielectric>
            </Spec>
            <Spec name="SPEC_LAYER_LYR-3_PLANE-2">
                <General type="MATERIAL">
                    <Property text="COPPER"/>
                </General>
                <General type="OTHER" comment="LAYER_TYPE">
                    <Property text="PLANE"/>
                </General>
                <General type="OTHER" comment="LAYER_IS_SHIELD">
                    <Property text="true"/>
                </General>
                <General type="OTHER" comment="LAYER_EMBEDDED_STATUS">
                    <Property text="NOT_EMBEDDED"/>
                </General>
                <Conductor type="CONDUCTIVITY">
                    <Property unit="MHO/CM" value="595900.000000"/>
                </Conductor>
            </Spec>
            <Spec name="SPEC_LAYER_DIELECTRIC_INDEX_7">
                <General type="MATERIAL">
                    <Property text="FR370HR 1x1080-71%"/>
                </General>
                <General type="OTHER" comment="LAYER_TYPE">
                    <Property text="DIELECTRIC"/>
                </General>
                <Dielectric type="DIELECTRIC_CONSTANT">
                    <Property value="3.63"/>
                </Dielectric>
            </Spec>
            <Spec name="SPEC_LAYER_BOTTOM">
                <General type="MATERIAL">
                    <Property text="COPPER"/>
                </General>
                <General type="OTHER" comment="LAYER_TYPE">
                    <Property text="CONDUCTOR"/>
                </General>
                <General type="OTHER" comment="LAYER_EMBEDDED_STATUS">
                    <Property text="NOT_EMBEDDED"/>
                </General>
                <Conductor type="CONDUCTIVITY">
                    <Property unit="MHO/CM" value="595900.000000"/>
                </Conductor>
            </Spec>
            <Spec name="SPEC_LAYER_SOLDERMASK_BOTTOM">
                <General type="MATERIAL">
                    <Property text="Soldermask"/>
                </General>
                <Dielectric type="DIELECTRIC_CONSTANT">
                    <Property value="4.2"/>
                </Dielectric>
                <Dielectric type="LOSS_TANGENT">
                    <Property value="0.024"/>
                </Dielectric>
            </Spec>
        </CadHeader>
        <CadData>
            <Layer name="SOLDERMASK_TOP" layerFunction="SOLDERMASK" side="TOP" polarity="POSITIVE"/>
            <Layer name="TOP" layerFunction="CONDUCTOR" side="TOP" polarity="POSITIVE"/>
            <Layer name="DIELECTRIC_INDEX_3" layerFunction="DIELPREG" side="INTERNAL" polarity="POSITIVE"/>
            <Layer name="LYR-2_PLANE-1" layerFunction="PLANE" side="INTERNAL" polarity="POSITIVE"/>
            <Layer name="DIELECTRIC_INDEX_5" layerFunction="DIELCORE" side="INTERNAL" polarity="POSITIVE"/>
            <Layer name="LYR-3_PLANE-2" layerFunction="PLANE" side="INTERNAL" polarity="POSITIVE"/>
            <Layer name="DIELECTRIC_INDEX_7" layerFunction="DIELPREG" side="INTERNAL" polarity="POSITIVE"/>
            <Layer name="BOTTOM" layerFunction="CONDUCTOR" side="BOTTOM" polarity="POSITIVE"/>
            <Layer name="SOLDERMASK_BOTTOM" layerFunction="SOLDERMASK" side="BOTTOM" polarity="POSITIVE"/>
            <Stackup name="PRIMARY" overallThickness="0.049996" tolPlus="10" tolMinus="10" whereMeasured="METAL">
                <StackupGroup name="GROUP_PRIMARY" thickness="0.049996" tolPlus="10" tolMinus="10">
                    <StackupLayer layerOrGroupRef="SOLDERMASK_TOP" thickness="0.0005" tolPlus="0.00" tolMinus="0.00" sequence="1">
                        <SpecRef id="SPEC_LAYER_SOLDERMASK_TOP"/>
                    </StackupLayer>
                    <StackupLayer layerOrGroupRef="TOP" thickness="0.0014500000000000001" tolPlus="0.00" tolMinus="0.00" sequence="2">
                        <SpecRef id="SPEC_LAYER_TOP"/>
                    </StackupLayer>
                    <StackupLayer layerOrGroupRef="DIELECTRIC_INDEX_3" thickness="0.003348" tolPlus="0.00" tolMinus="0.00" sequence="3">
                        <SpecRef id="SPEC_LAYER_DIELECTRIC_INDEX_3"/>
                    </StackupLayer>
                    <StackupLayer layerOrGroupRef="LYR-2_PLANE-1" thickness="7.0E-4" tolPlus="0.00" tolMinus="0.00" sequence="4">
                        <SpecRef id="SPEC_LAYER_LYR-2_PLANE-1"/>
                    </StackupLayer>
                    <StackupLayer layerOrGroupRef="DIELECTRIC_INDEX_5" thickness="0.039" tolPlus="0.00" tolMinus="0.00" sequence="5">
                        <SpecRef id="SPEC_LAYER_DIELECTRIC_INDEX_5"/>
                    </StackupLayer>
                    <StackupLayer layerOrGroupRef="LYR-3_PLANE-2" thickness="7.0E-4" tolPlus="0.00" tolMinus="0.00" sequence="6">
                        <SpecRef id="SPEC_LAYER_LYR-3_PLANE-2"/>
                    </StackupLayer>
                    <StackupLayer layerOrGroupRef="DIELECTRIC_INDEX_7" thickness="0.003348" tolPlus="0.00" tolMinus="0.00" sequence="7">
                        <SpecRef id="SPEC_LAYER_DIELECTRIC_INDEX_7"/>
                    </StackupLayer>
                    <StackupLayer layerOrGroupRef="BOTTOM" thickness="0.0014500000000000001" tolPlus="0.00" tolMinus="0.00" sequence="8">
                        <SpecRef id="SPEC_LAYER_BOTTOM"/>
                    </StackupLayer>
                    <StackupLayer layerOrGroupRef="SOLDERMASK_BOTTOM" thickness="0.0005" tolPlus="0.00" tolMinus="0.00" sequence="9">
                        <SpecRef id="SPEC_LAYER_SOLDERMASK_BOTTOM"/>
                    </StackupLayer>
                </StackupGroup>
            </Stackup>
            <Step name="MyFile_IPC_File">
                <LayerFeature layerRef="SOLDERMASK_TOP">
                    <Set>
                        <ColorRef id="COLOR_SOLDERMASK_TOP"/>
                    </Set>
                </LayerFeature>
                <LayerFeature layerRef="TOP">
                    <Set>
                        <ColorRef id="COLOR_TOP"/>
                    </Set>
                </LayerFeature>
                <LayerFeature layerRef="LYR-2_PLANE-1">
                    <Set>
                        <ColorRef id="COLOR_LYR-2_PLANE-1"/>
                    </Set>
                </LayerFeature>
                <LayerFeature layerRef="LYR-3_PLANE-2">
                    <Set>
                        <ColorRef id="COLOR_LYR-3_PLANE-2"/>
                    </Set>
                </LayerFeature>
                <LayerFeature layerRef="BOTTOM">
                    <Set>
                        <ColorRef id="COLOR_BOTTOM"/>
                    </Set>
                </LayerFeature>
                <LayerFeature layerRef="SOLDERMASK_BOTTOM">
                    <Set>
                        <ColorRef id="COLOR_SOLDERMASK_BOTTOM"/>
                    </Set>
                </LayerFeature>
            </Step>
        </CadData>
    </Ecad>
</IPC-2581>
```

Comment: What version of Altium Designer? This may be something to contact Altium or Sierra about (or both), if it's just an incompatible version/format.

Comment: How big is the xml file? Can you post it?

Comment: @JYelton it is altium version 23.8.1

Comment: @Voltage Spike - It is 13KB, I will try to post it now.

Comment: Altium's Layer Stack Manager seems to change with every new release. What worked one time probably won't work now. I recommend just creating the layer stack based on the Sierra Circuits information; it's probably faster and a good learning opportunity.